# Is it possible to XPORT with labels longer than 40 characters with SAS 9.3?

Tags: sas

This was asked before but the author was using SAS9.2. I read this [Usage Note 46944: New SAS® transport format and tools available](http://support.sas.com/kb/46/944.html) and thought it would be possible to have up to 256 characters for labels, but my labels are still truncated when I am using PROC COPY to get transport file.
So can we have xpt file with variable labels more than 40 characters? If yes, how can we do it?

Comment: Are you possibly referring to CPORT?  CPORT is the "newer" version of SAS transport files.

Comment: I see. I can only use PROC COPY. So it is still not possible to have label more than 40 characters. Thank you (was wishing for your help^_^)!

Answer (score 1):

I have to use PROC COPY, but PROC CPORT can output a xpt file with variable label longer than 40. Here is the code.

```
PROC CPORT DATA=Work.test FILE="...\QS.xpt";
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work on the same environment, you can use proc cport and proc cimport

But if you work across environments e.g., create transport file in Windows and extract datasets from transport file in Unix, you can use %loc2xpt (with format=V8) and %xpt2loc macros starting on SAS 9.3 https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_038/movefile/p13q0v60f08mj3n1ebm8salcpkmh.htm

proc copy uses xport engine which is only working with V5 rules (variable label up to 40 characters)